# 401: Unauthorized when connecting to Reporting Services

Tags: domain, ssrs

Ok, so here's the layout:

We have our AppServer and our Database Server.

Our AppServer is trying to connect to our Database Server which has Sql Reporting Services on it. However they are different machines with different domains.

We have an Program that connects and uses a Connection string to connect either by "TrustedConnection" or using a strict User Id=XXX;Password=YYYY;

TrustedConnection doesn't work, since it's trying to connect as APPDOMAIN/User (and since I can't add APPDOMAIN/User to the DatabaseServer (It has a different domain) I tried setting the data source within Reporting Services = a strict username/password (lets call it USER for username and PASS for password).

I can "test" the connection within reporting services and it is successful. However using our config and changing it to be User Id=USER;Password=PASS results in this error.

And since I can't use TrustedConnection (since they are different domains....unless theirs some way around that)

Im not sure what else could be causing the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default SSRS only allows connections using Negotiate and NTLM authentication.  You will need to add Basic Authentication as an allowed authentication method to your SSRS installation in order to use the simple Username and Password credentials.  Use the following post to guide you through the setup: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281309(v=sql.100).aspx.